# I need To perform an Insert Operation On Data Category In Salesforce by apex

Tags: apex, data-category

How Can we perform insert operation on Data Category by Apex in Salesforce .

Comment: Please remove the unwanted tags in your question.

Comment: Data category is a kind of metadata, you cannot insert it by apex. Please go through [data category group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_datacategorygroup.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Reshma ,for the quick response ..
Is there any other way of Achieving it ?. Apart from manually adding the Data Category .

Comment: You can create it using packge.xml file.

Comment: Can we Do it by Data Loader ??...

Comment: No. Its yet to be delivered in ideaexchange https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YYZsAAO

Comment: Can we Use SOAP Api to Insert it ?@Reshma

Comment: @SR07 have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this cannot be achieved by a simple Apex but actually this can be done my Metadata API and potentially by a complex solution that uses Metadata API port for Apex

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_datacategorygroup.htm

Anyway, it is better to use Deployment or packaging.

This metadata object is available for unlocked packages.
[image]